# Unable to update my Bash in Mac by MacPorts

Tags: macos, bash, macports

I updated unsuccessfully my Bash to 3.2.48 by MacPorts.

It seems that I do not have it active, since I get

```
echo $BASH_VERSION
3.2.17(1)-release
```

**How can you make the newest Bash active** such that I get it for my login shell?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Run the following code, for instance to change your shell to the newest Bash installed by MacPorts

```
chsh -s /opt/local/bin/bash
```

If that gives you the message,

> "`non-standard shell`"

you will need to add

```
/opt/local/bin/bash
```

to

```
/etc/shells
```

Note that `/etc/shells` is just a text file, so you can edit it directly if you authenticate as root. You can programmatically change it by the command

```
sudo -s
Password:
# echo /opt/local/bin/bash >> /etc/shells
```

If your first chsh command failed, run it now again if you managed to change the above file.

Comment: If you encounter problems running the port application, you may additionally need to update your bash profiles. See http://superuser.com/a/366645/114131 for more information.

Comment: Note that one might need to reorder the entries in `/etc/shells` such that the new `bash` location precedes other ones, for everything to work properly.

Comment: @zhermes: Not true. Order in /etc/shells has no effect on anything.

Comment: @Noldorin changing the order fixed the problem for me.  That's all I can say.

Comment: Okay, I believe you. :) Maybe you did not specify the full path when using chsh then... odd though. It's non-standard behaviour; maybe your system is borked.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing it's installed but not being used as your login shell.

You can change the shell using dscl on the command line.

At the dscl prompt type the following:

```
list Local/Default/Users
read Local/Default/Users/<your username here>
change Local/Default/Users/<your username here> UserShell /bin/bash /opt/local/bin/bash
```

I have another example of dscl use on my [blog](http://hasno.info) if it helps.

Comment: First you have to add the new shell to /etc/shells:

# sudo echo /opt/local/bin/bash >> /etc/shells

Comment: change Local/Default/Users/simpatico UserShell /bin/bash /opt/local/bin/bash
<main> attribute status: eDSAttributeNotFound
<dscl_cmd> DS Error: -14134 (eDSAttributeNotFound)

Answer (score 2):

You can switch your login shell, from your existing Mac OS X login shell (by default its `/bin/bash` shipped with Mac OS X), to MacPorts `/opt/local/bin/bash` just by using the following shell script:

```
#!/opt/local/bin/bash
if [ `grep /opt/local/bin/bash /etc/shells` ]; 
then 
    echo /opt/local/bin/bash | chsh -s /opt/local/bin/bash;     
else 
    echo /opt/local/bin/bash | sudo tee -a /etc/shells; 
    chsh -s /opt/local/bin/bash; 
fi
```

Comment: Do not test the output of grep, test its exit status. `if grep -Fxq /opt/local/bin/bash /etc/shells; then`