# Install RVM on Mac OSX 10.5

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm, upgrade

Need to use SASS / Compass locally, but the Ruby on my old Mac OSX on this machine is not compatible: `sass requires Ruby version >= 1.8.7.`. After research it seems like I need RVM, but haven't been able to find out how to install this on my computer so that I can upgrade my Ruby.

Tried this, for example:

```
\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
```

Returns this:

```
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html
```

Can anyone give me step-by-step instructions on how to do this? Please keep in mind that I am not very skilled in the terminal, so any copy-and-paste snippets would be helpful. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Which `curl` are you using? System? Homebrew? MacPorts? `which curl` should tell you.

Comment: `which curl` returns `/usr/bin/curl`. But I installed HomeBrew earlier as part of the steps included in an online tutorial. To no avail, unfortunately... Thanks for any ideas @tadman

Comment: You probably have trouble with `curl` on other sites, right? What's `curl -I https://google.com/` say?

Comment: I think it is okay.. It returns `HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://www.google.com/
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Mon, 15 Apr 2013 22:10:10 GMT
Expires: Wed, 15 May 2013 22:10:10 GMT
Cache-Control: public, max-age=2592000
Server: gws
Content-Length: 220
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN` But I'm not very experienced with Terminal or curl. Just need to get it to work so that I can use SASS for CSS development. Thanks for any ideas @tadman.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your certificates:

```
cert_dir="$( openssl version -d | awk -F'"' '{print $2}' )"
mkdir -p "$cert_dir"
security find-certificate -a -p /Library/Keychains/System.keychain > "$cert_dir/cert.pem"
security find-certificate -a -p /System/Library/Keychains/SystemRootCertificates.keychain >> "$cert_dir/cert.pem"
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could try to add `insecure` into `~/.curlrc`:

```
echo insecure >> ~/.curlrc
```

To avoid the certificate problem.

Comment: Thanks but now facing problem of my Bash version for some reason.. See the comment below if you dont mind...

Comment: Well, I see your point. I think this link may solve your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10574969/how-do-i-install-bash-3-2-25-on-mac-os-x-10-5-8

Answer (score -1):

Try tacking a -k in your curl options.

Comment: Thanks, but now getting error: `BASH 3.2.25 required (you have 3.2.17(1)-release)`. Ugh. Any ideas? Tried the steps illustrated on [this StackOverflow Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10574969/how-do-i-install-bash-3-2-25-on-mac-os-x-10-5-8), but for some reason when I `echo $BASH_VERSION` it still returns 3.2.17.. Is this because I dont have XCode on this machine?? Thanks for any ideas!