# How can I install ruby 2.2.1 if I am on 2.2.2?

Tags: ruby, installation, version

How can I install ruby 2.2.1 if I'm currently on 2.2.2 ... I need to rewind back a version because ruby 2.2.2 seems to have having some issues loading my projects in the terminal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RVM is a version management system that does exactly this.

https://rvm.io/

Once you install see the faqs

https://rvm.io/rvm/basics

Comment: But would that have to have been installed prior, I just installed ruby on this computer and the most recent version is 2.2.2 and I need 2.2.1?

Comment: no. It allows you to traverse backwards like you wish. I prefer it to Rbenv

Comment: basically you install RVM independently, then install the versions (as many as you wish!)  of ruby you want, and then to switch to the version of ruby you say ```use ruby x.x.x```

Comment: did you follow the instructions on the site?

Comment: yes... 'gpg' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file is what it replies back when I put the gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3 in the command line

Comment: ```\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash``` Try this command only and let me know what you see.

Comment: which directory are you in?

Comment: users, do I need to be in the directory of the project?

Comment: BASH 3.2.25 required (you have 3.1.23(6) release)

Comment: see the top answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10574969/how-do-i-install-bash-3-2-25-on-mac-os-x-10-5-8

Answer (score 1):

An option for Ruby version management is [**rbenv**](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv). I prefer it to RVM because it's not as intrusive (it doesn't need to be loaded into your shell, it doesn't override shell commands, it doesn't manage gemsets, etc.).

---

In your case, to install an older Ruby version, you can do the following, once rbenv is installed:

Check for available Ruby versions:

```
rbenv install -l
```

The above should show a list of all versions available (in your scenario, 2.2.1 should be an available option). Then once you have picked out a version you wish to install, the following command can be run next:

```
rbenv install 2.2.1
```

Finally, To switch between ruby versions you can run:

```
rbenv local 2.2.1
```

Or to set Ruby 2.2.1 to be default globally:

```
rbenv global 2.2.1
```

More info, such as installation instructions, can be found in the [README](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/blob/master/README.md)

Hope that was helpful to you!

Comment: But would that have to have been installed prior, I just installed ruby on this computer and the most recent version is 2.2.2 and I need 2.2.1?

Comment: You can actually install previous versions. Once you have it installed you can do something like `rbenv install 2.2.1`.

Comment: I keep getting rbenv: command not found, I don't think I installed it correctly

Comment: Make sure you followed the installation instructions and also installed ruby-build with it. That's usually why that `command not found` error pops up. Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

An another option for Ruby version management is [chruby](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby).