# source /.bash_profile command provide error

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

I run the command `source ~/.bash_profile` and get the following error:

```
$ source ~/.bash_profile 
-sh: /Users/chaklader/.sdkman/contrib/completion/bash/sdk: line 37: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
-sh: /Users/chaklader/.sdkman/contrib/completion/bash/sdk: line 37: `           done < <(curl --silent "${SDKMAN_CANDIDATES_API}/candidates/all")'
```

The login shell that I use is `bin/sh`:

[image]

Whats the issue here and how to solve it?

Comment: Are you in `sh` or in `bash`? The `<(...)` construct (_process substitution_) exists only in `bash`.

Comment: I use bin/sh in the terminal.

Comment: Then don't try to use it to execute bash scripts.

Comment: @Shawn okay but this was working just fine munites earlier :(

Comment: Try to change your "Login shell" to `/bin/bash`, or `/usr/local/bin/bash` if you installed a more recent version of bash.

Comment: @Philippe I find a good solution for the issue.

Comment: I recommend you install an even more recent version of bash, for ex. 5.1

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved the issue with the provided steps:

Install Homebrew from the docs on their homepage
Install Git using Homebrew (optional, but nice to have a more up-to-date git)

```
brew install git
```

Now install bash:

```
brew install bash
```

Add this install of bash to the allowed shells list:

```
echo '/usr/local/bin/bash' | sudo tee -a /etc/shells;
```

Homebrew installs things to /usr/local/Cellar/ by default, then symlinks any binaries to /usr/local/bin, so you've now got the latest bash sitting at /usr/local/bin/bash
Finally, change your shell to use this new one:

```
chsh -s /usr/local/bin/bash
```

Open a new terminal window/tab, and run these commands to double-check your work:

```
$ echo $SHELL
/usr/local/bin/bash
$ echo $BASH_VERSION
5.1.8(1)-release
```

This also solved the issue for running the `source ~/.bash_profile` whenever I open a new window in the terminal.

Reference:

The answer is from here [How do I install Bash >= 3.2.25 on Mac OS X 10.5.8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10574969/how-do-i-install-bash-3-2-25-on-mac-os-x-10-5-8) by user jeffbyrnes