# How to make oh-my-zsh use the latest zsh version?

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

I am using zsh with oh-my-zsh in iTerm (OS X). I encounter the following problem:

1. `echo $ZSH_VERSION` returns 4.3.11.
2. I run `upgrade_oh_my_zsh` successfully.
3. `echo $ZSH_VERSION` again returns 4.3.11.
4. I run `brew install zsh` / `brew upgrade zsh` and I get a `Error: zsh-5.0.2 already installed`.
5. Yet even after I restart iTerm `echo $ZSH_VERSION` returns 4.3.11.

How do I make OMZ use the latest zsh version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the issue. My `/etc/paths` had already `/usr/local/bin` at the top. When I opened `/usr/local/bin/` I saw that besides `zsh`, I also have `zsh-5.2.0`. I tried `chsh -s /usr/local/bin/zsh-5.2.0` but that didn't help. I removed `zsh` and renamed `zsh-5.2.0` to `zsh` -> also to no avail. I saw that `zsh-5.2.0` was pointing to `/usr/local/Cellar/zsh/5.0.2/bin/zsh-5.0.2` and previously I had seen that the original `zsh` was pointing to `/bin/zsh`. So what helped me was this:

- opened `/usr/local/Cellar/zsh/5.0.2/bin/` -> contained both `zsh` and `zsh-5.2.0`.
- copied `zsh` from there to `/bin/` and overwrote `/bin/zsh`
- restarted iTerm

Answer (score 3):

I'm glad you've found a solution. Some notes:

1. `oh-my-zsh` is a zsh *configuration framework*. It is not "zsh", merely the configuration files for the shell. Upgrading `oh-my-zsh` and `zsh` itself are two separate, largely unrelated tasks.
2. Overwriting `/bin/zsh` with a new binary is one solution. Another is to use a [symlink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) - probably from `/usr/local/Cellar/zsh/5.0.2/bin/zsh-5.2.0` to somewhere in your `$PATH` (like `/usr/local/bin/`), and setting the shell using `chsh`. The advantage of a symlink is that you've kept all the binaries (so you still have `4.3`, `5.0`, `5.2`).
3. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/791227/unable-to-update-my-bash-in-mac-by-macports) may shed some light on why `chsh` didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I have the following in my ~/.zshrc. It will find a usable zsh in a given list of directories, sort them by version number and exec the newest one.

```
if [[ $- == *i* ]]; then
    arg=$(
        for dir in \
            /usr/local/bin \
            /usr/gnu/bin \
            /usr/sfw/bin \
            /bin \
            /usr/bin
        do
            arg=$dir/zsh

            # Make sure the shell is a readable, executable file.
            if [[ ! -f $arg || ! -r $arg || ! -x $arg ]]; then
                continue
            fi

            # Print sortable version number and path to shell.
            ver=$( $arg -c 'echo $ZSH_VERSION' 2>/dev/null )
            if [[ -n $ver ]]; then
                printf '%03u%03u%03u %s\n' $( echo $ver | tr '.' ' ' ) $arg
            fi
        done | sort -r | head -1 | cut -c11-
    )

    if [[ -n $arg && $arg != $SHELL ]]; then
        echo "Switching SHELL to $arg"
        export SHELL=$arg
        exec $SHELL -li
    fi
fi
```

If you want it to search the contents of the PATH variable, you can use

```
for dir in $( echo "$PATH" | tr ':' ' ' ); do
    (...)
```

If you have spaces in your directory names, you must use something like

```
printf '%s\n' "$PATH" | tr ':' '\n' | while read dir; do
    (...)
```

and add double quotes around $arg and $SHELL some places.