# How can I get iTerm to use the newer version of bash that brew shows? Change a user's shell on OSX

Tags: macos, bash, shell, default, homebrew

When I do the `brew upgrade`I see I do have the newer version.  How can I use it?

```
$ bash -version
GNU bash, version 3.2.51(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin13)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
$ brew upgrade bash
Error: bash-4.2.45 already installed
$ which bash
/bin/bash
```

I do see I have

```
/usr/local/Cellar/bash/4.2.45/bin
```

but when i do

```
$ /usr/local/Cellar/bash/4.2.45/bin/bash
```

I am still in

```
$ bash -version
GNU bash, version 3.2.51(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin13)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
08:06:45 mdurrant w89123148q1 /usr/local/Cellar/bash/4.2.45/bin master
```

The contents of `/etc/shells` are:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/bash/4.2.45/bin/bash  # (I added this)
/usr/local/bin/bash
/bin/bash
/bin/csh
/bin/ksh
/bin/sh
/bin/tcsh
/bin/zsh
```

chsh didn't seem to do what I hoped:

```
$ chsh -s /usr/local/Cellar/bash/4.2.45/bin/bash
Changing shell for mdurrant.
Password for mdurrant:
chsh: /usr/local/Cellar/bash/4.2.45/bin/bash: non-standard shell
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.51(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin13)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

I have the file here:

```
$ l /usr/local/Cellar/bash/4.2.45/bin/bash
-r-xr-xr-x  1 mdurrant  admin  699688 Apr 14 19:54 /usr/local/Cellar/bash/4.2.45/bin/bash*
```

I've yet to actually see the new bash version for anyway that I try interactively to invoke it.

`$ echo $BASH_VERSION` shows

```
3.2.51(1)-release
```

I tried using dscl and did

```
> change Local/Default/Users/mdurrant UserShell /bin/bash /usr/local/Cellar/bash/4.2.45/bin/bash
```

but got

```
<main> attribute status: eDSAttributeNotFound
<dscl_cmd> DS Error: -14134 (eDSAttributeNotFound)
```

and now list shows

```
> UserShell: /usr/local/Cellar/bash/4.2.45/bin/bash
```

Comment: Why don't you change the login shell (using `chsh` or equivalent on Mac) instead?

Comment: I tried.  didn't work.  adding to above

Comment: Not sure if `/usr/local/bin/bash` and `/bin/bash` are the same.  If you want to keep both the versions (3.2.x and 4.2.x) around, then have `/usr/local/bin/bash` point to the older one and `/bin/bash` point to the newer one.

Comment: The error using `chsh` can be fixed by adding the path to new bash in `/etc/shells`.

Comment: Just put `/usr/local/Cellar/bash/4.2.45/bin/bash` in `/etc/shells` and then `chsh`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to update my Bash in Mac by MacPorts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/791227/unable-to-update-my-bash-in-mac-by-macports)

Comment: unfortunately the MacPorts question/answer was not my issue.  I tried again: `brew install bash`, adding /usr/local/Cellar/bash/4.2.45/bin/bash to /etc/shells and run doing chsh -s /usr/local/Cellar/bash/4.2.45/bin/bash but nothing changed.  Still running 3.2.51

Comment: Your user is hosed up. I've changed back and forth from /bin/bash to /usr/local/bin/bash and only `sudo su - $USER` is needed to get the $BASH_VERSION to change as expected.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

`bash --version` (or `bash -version`) will NOT report the CURRENT shell's version, but the version of the `bash` executable that comes FIRST IN THE `$PATH`.

*[Note: OSX 10.10 (Yosemite) is the first OSX version where `/usr/local/bin` is placed BEFORE system paths such as `/bin` in the `$PATH`. Up to 10.9, system paths came first. Thus, at the time the OP asked his question, `bash --version` reported the SYSTEM's bash's version (`/bin/bash`), not the Homebrew-installed version (`/usr/local/bin/bash`)]*

If you want to know the current Bash shell's version, use:

```
echo $BASH_VERSION
```

In other words: your shell may well have been changed successfully - your *test* was flawed.

---

**You *can* use `chsh`** to change the current user's shell, as follows:

*[Update: Switched to using `/usr/local/bin/bash` and later `"$(brew --prefix)/bin"` (to account for the fact that on M1 Macs and above the Homebrew root dir. is `/opt/homewbrew` rather than `/usr/local`) rather than a specific, versioned path in `$(brew --prefix)/Cellar/bash/<version>/bin/bash`, as Homebrew will automatically keep the symlink at `$(brew --prefix)/bin/bash` pointed to the most recent installed version. Tip of the hat to @drevicko.]*

```
# Determine the full path of the new shell.
newShell="$(brew --prefix)/bin/bash"
# Add the full path to the list of allowed shells - SUDO REQUIRED
sudo bash -c "echo \"$newShell\" >> /etc/shells"
# Then change to the new shell.
chsh -s "$newShell"
```

Note that you'll be prompted for your password.
Any terminal tab/window you create from that point on will already use the new shell.

Bonus tip from @bmike: If you want to replace the *current* shell instance with an instance of the new shell right away, run:

```
exec su - $USER  # instantly replaces current shell with an instance of the new shell
```

Note that you'll be prompted for your password again.

---

**Alternatively, use `dscl`** - the OSX Directory Services CLI - to change the current user's shell; this is **more cumbersome**, however.

To *examine* the current user's shell, use:

```
dscl . -read /Users/$USER UserShell  # e.g. (default): 'UserShell: /bin/bash'
```

or, more simply, `echo $SHELL`, which outputs only the file path (e.g., `/bin/bash`).

To *change* the current user's shell to, e.g., `$(brew --prefix)/bin/bash`, use:

```
# SUDO REQUIRED
sudo dscl . -change /Users/$USER UserShell /bin/bash "$(brew --prefix)/bin/bash"
```

Note:

- the penultimate (second-to-last) argument must be the *value currently in effect*.
- it is NOT necessary for the new value to be contained in `/etc/shells` for *interactive* use, but the comments in `/etc/shells` state `Ftpd will not allow users to connect who are not using one of these shells.`
- simply quit and restart `Terminal.app` (or `iTerm.app`) for the change to take effect - verify the new shell with `echo $BASH_VERSION` - a reboot is NOT required.

---

**Explanation of errors encountered by the OP**:

- `chsh: /usr/local/Cellar/bash/4.2.45/bin/bash: non-standard shell` implies that `/usr/local/Cellar/bash/4.2.45/bin/bash` was not - not yet, or not in this exact form - listed in `/etc/shells`.
- `<main> attribute status: eDSAttributeNotFound`: this `dscl` error occurs when the penultimate (next-to-last) argument specified for the `-change` command does not match the *current* attribute value - it is an - admittedly strange - requirement that an attribute's current value be specified in order to change it.

While the question suggests that both conditions were met, I suspect that they weren't met at the *right* times, due to experimentation.

Comment: You are correct and echoing the version is probably the source of this error. I still wonder at the `chsh` error - perhaps that's due to the "Cellar" in the `/etc/shells`?

Comment: @bmike: The `chsh` error `non-standard shell` normally indicates that the specified shell is NOT in `/etc/shells`; however, you can bypass the problem by using `dscl` - see my updated answer.

Comment: I agree that normally that error is due to /etc/shells, but the OP has lines for both potential homebrew shells so unless there's some oddball permissions on the file - it's likely some other corruption was foiling steps that normally would work.

Comment: @bmike: I suspect that the OP tried various things at various times, so the sequence listed in the question may not reflect the actual conditions - the OP's eventual own answer seems to confirm that. I've added an explanatory section to my answer.

Comment: @bmike: Neat `su` trick, I've added it to the answer; seems that prefixing `su` with `sudo` is not needed - it prompts on demand. (Another caveat is that exiting out of the new shell brings you back to the old one).

Comment: @drevicko: You are absolutely correct, thanks for pointing that out - answer updated.

Comment: On M1 Macs the path for homebrew's executables is `/opt/homebrew/bin` and not `/usr/local/bin`. I added that to the PATH to `.bash_profile`'s top for login shells.

Comment: Thanks, @Sid - I've updated the answer to use `$(brew --prefix)/bin`, which should work on both Intel and M1+ Macs. To fully initialize the Homebrew environment on M1+ Macs, place `eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"` in `~/.bash_profile` or the equivalent file for other shells, such as `~/.zprofile` for `zsh`.

Answer (score 3):

The answer was that, yes, I needed to:

- `brew install bash`
- add the path to `/etc/shells`
- use `chsh -s`:  `chsh -s /usr/local/Cellar/bash/4.2.45/bin/bash`
- possibly use dscl to set the shell, i.e. within `dscl` type

  `> change Local/Default/Users/<username> UserShell /bin/bash /usr/local/bin/zsh`

most importantly:

- quit the terminal (really close the app, not just its windows).
- **reboot**

echoing `$BASH_VERSION` after rebooting showed `4.2.45(2)-release`

Comment: Turns out that `dscl` is all you need (no need for `chsh`), and there's no need to reboot - see my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you Michael - still an issue seven years later....

Answer (score 2):

Current versions of iTerm2 allow for a simpler & less intrusive change. In Preferences > Profiles > General, under "Command" change "Login shell" to eg.:

```
/usr/local/bin/bash -l
```

Comment: This helped for me. Either for historic reasons or by default for me this setting was explicitly set to "/bin/bash", which means all other magic is absolutely useless, as we explicitly tell iTerm to start with this bash executable. I just changed it to "Login Shell" and it worked, as I did all the steps of installing the new bash version properly.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have to do anything else than to run:

```
echo /usr/local/bin/bash|sudo tee -a /etc/shells;chsh -s /usr/local/bin/bash
```

After that iTerm and Terminal should use `/usr/local/bin/bash` for new shells.

`chsh`, `dscl`, and the Users & Groups preference pane all modify `/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/$USER.plist`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming one only wishes to change the shell used by iTerm (and not the user's default shell), the following straightforward solution is possible as of version 3.4 (see [iTerm2#3624330](https://github.com/gnachman/iTerm2/commit/3624330bb2ae1a6aa41842b9b4e71ffb4f59945a)):

In iTerm, under **Preferences > Profiles > General > Command** select **Custom Shell** from the dropdown, and put the path to your desired shell (e.g. `/usr/local/bin/bash`) in the "Enter full path to shell" field to run it as a login shell.

Also refer to the [General Profile Preferences](https://iterm2.com/documentation-preferences-profiles-general.html) section of the iTerm2 Documentation.